# How to set "Use 1st column as labels" turned on by default while using numbered label columns

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to plot a line chart and add a chart editor button similar to [the example](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#chart_editor) in the Google Code Playground. [Here](https://github.com/gokceneraslan/googplot/blob/master/testfile.html) is my html file. The difference between playground example and my plot is that my all column types are number including the first column.

My plot seems OK, there are two lines as expected but when I open the editor window, "Use 1st column as labels" checkbox is **not** selected and there are **three** lines instead of two. My label column which is of number type is also drawn.

Plot on the Chart Editor seems OK when I select the checkbox, but I don't want to do that manually. How should I do this automatically?

By the way, I think Discrete vs Continuous page in developers.google.com is related but I couldn't find any solutions there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Annotation role instead of a third data column?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles

Admittedly that functionality is quite well hidden, I didn't spot it until I explicitly looked for it.

It appends the annotations to the first series of the chart, looks quite nice, and can have hover-over text as well.

Hope that helps!